# How to get Payload (io.rsocket.Payload) in Spring Boot @MessageMapping Controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-reactive, rsocket

I am connecting to a Spring Boot RSocket app from RSocket-Java. In the server I have @MessageMapping. how do I access RSocket Payload on Server.

Comment: Could you please attach an example to give more advanced answer?
Also for getting payload you need to annotate emthod parameter via @Payload annotation or use Message<YourClassType> message class should be spring import not javax.jms and execute message.getPayload()

Answer (score 0):

@Payload works thanks. Closing this question, although, it doesn't work when Metadata is present in DefaultPayload. I have posted that as separate question.